# Schengen Visa - Change of Destination?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, germany, italy

I have a Schengen Visa that I issued from the German embassy back in 2011 (it's still valid till mid-2014). I never actually went to Germany though.

It says visa type: C, multiple entries, 90 days duration.

I want to go soon to France and from there to Italy. My understanding is that I will have to first enter from Germany though, is that correct? Also, at the top, it says valid for: "Schengener Staaten" which I take is Schengen states, but it also has a "D" for  Deutschland on the far right. What does this "D" mean. Only valid for Germany? Or that entry must be via Germany?

Comment: You can enter Schengen area from any state, it does not have to be from the issuance state.

Comment: But what does the "D" mean? Why doesn't it simply say valid for Schengen States?

Comment: It maybe means the issuance state... No worries mate, you,can visit any Schengen state, I have multiple first hand experiences with this.

Comment: There is definitely no blanket requirement to enter through Germany, the rules for short-stay visa do not allow that. If the visa was somehow limited to Germany, it wouldn't say “Schengener Staaten” and you would not have the right to go to France, period (even through Germany). Border guards might however ask why you requested a visa from Germany and never went there.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point