# To travel to Athens with a valid French Schengen visa, do I need to obtain a Greek Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, greece

I am an Indian national holding a valid multiple entry French Schengen visa for four years. I would like to visit Athens, Greece to attend a conference in September. Can I travel with this French Schengen visa or do I need to take a fresh Schengen visa from Greece?

Answer (score 4):

If you already went to France, you can use the French visa without any issue, provided you fulfill all the usual conditions (have health insurance, sufficient financial means, didn't [stay too long in the Schengen area](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule), etc.)

If you haven't been to France yet, it's still possible but you might need to explain why you got a French visa to go to Greece, see [Can I use my Schengen visa for a completely different purpose and entry point?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point) and [Use of unused Schengen visa to travel to Switzerland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/use-of-unused-schengen-visa-to-travel-to-switzerland?lq=1)

Furthermore, having a four-year multiple-entry visa suggests you are a trusted traveller (UK resident?) so I wouldn't expect any problem.