# Going to Schengen countries for the second time with a multi entry visa

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I got a multi-entry schengen visa valid for 3 years last year from the German embassy and i did go to Germany for 2 weeks, this year am going to france for 2 weeks and will spend NO TIME in Germany

can i use the same visa as it is still valid or i need a new visa from the French embassy?

Comment: it's about other countries, but the same rules apply in the whole schengen area - you don't need a new visa.

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/to-travel-to-athens-with-a-valid-french-schengen-visa-do-i-need-to-obtain-a-gre and other related questions. Since you have already used your visa to go to Germany and it's a multiple-entry visa with a long validity period, it's completely fine.