# Can I apply for a new German Schengen visa, when my first Czech Schengen visa has not expired but only allows me to enter once?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, multiple-entry, czech-republic

I have a *single entry* Schengen visa from the Czech embassy in London due from March 22, 2015 to April 12, 2015 and the duration of stay is only 7 days. I planned to stay in the Czech Republic from March 22, 2015 to March 28, 2015 and then fly back to the UK. However, I also want to travel to Germany from April 5, 2015 to April 9, 2015. Could I, at this stage, apply for a new Schengen visa from the German embassy, or should I cancel the Czech visa first and apply for a new one?

I am a Chinese international student but study in the UK.

Comment: Given that all of these dates are in the past, he may not care about the answer anymore.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46689/visiting-two-schengen-countries-coming-back-home-in-between-do-i-apply-for-sin and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/use-of-unused-schengen-visa-to-travel-to-switzerland

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what can or cannot be done but you can always apply. If the consulate cannot issue a visa for a technical reason like that, they should decline to process the application, which means you would get back your visa fee and the documents you submitted. In principle, they should also tell you that quickly. There is no risk of an actual visa refusal, with all its unpleasant consequences.

Unfortunately, because the German consulate in London uses a third-party outsourcing company to handle visa applications, [there is apparently a non-refundable GBP 15 service charge on top of the visa fee](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist-visafees.html) and it might be more difficult to get competent advice for a special case like yours.