# Can a tour operator cancel a visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I had applied for Schengen visa with tour operator Thomas Cook and also received the visa with 30 days validity. At the end, because of rescheduling in their itinerary, we had to cancel our trip with them. They agreed to refund the full amount except visa fees. Now, I am thinking of traveling alone as my visa is still valid.

When I originally submitted my documents for visa, there was no flight bookings and hotel reservations given by Thomas Cook. I am kind of apprehensive and anxious if they can cancel my visa by calling the embassy, since I was supposed to go with them and canceled on their trip.

Can they do that and would the embassy inform me of such a decision if it was made without my knowledge and communication? Also, is there a way to know of visa status online so that I know it hasn't been canceled?

Comment: While Thomas Cook may not be able to (or even try to) get your visa cancelled, if you significantly change the itinerary, you may be denied entry (and have your visa cancelled) at the port of entry. See [this about changing _main destination_](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47305/50234), [changing itinerary and hotel booking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44258/50234), [changing flight dates after getting visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45800/50234) and [Can I use my Schengen visa for a completely different purpose](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26939/50234)

Comment: Yup, main destination is still the same. I had not given any itineary, hotel bookings or flights while submitting my visa to the VFS, and the purpose of visa is obviously still the same. I have talked with lots of people who have said itinearies change all the time and it's nothing to be concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

Once the valid visa is issued by the embassy, I highly doubt it can be cancelled by a local tours and travel company.  They would need to fill in additional paperwork to cancel the visa. Also since they are not refunding the visa fees, its proof that they dont expect you to travel with them in spite of having a valid visa. I think you should not worry about it.

Comment: That's great, I hope not so either. Do you know what kind of paperwork would that require?

Comment: I've never heard of such paperwork.

Comment: By no means can a tour operator cancel someone's visa. No amount of paperwork would achieve that. Cancelling a visa upon holder's request is anyway a weird concept. I don't think it exists. If you change your plans and don't want to travel, your visa will simply expire. Visa fees are always non-refundable, so what's the point? Visas can be cancelled only by the issuing country in case the holder violated the terms of stay, committed a crime, their application was fraudulent or for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Tour operator normally could not cancel a visa (and not for Schengen), but they may withdraw some guarantees, so the visa could become useless.

Visa could also not be valid (but this is different from cancelled), if circumstances changed in a significant way. This may be the case of some tour operators, but it is for very special cases (specific tour with specific circumstances [I would say organized, but not touristic], for specific people [e.g. students visiting UN or medical organization coming from few particular countries where visa were seldom given)

We do not have all information, but if you do a touristic visit not very dissimilar to original one, it is not a problem. Also for this reason (I think), they will not refund the visa costs: you can still use it.

Comment: It's a tourist visa though and it's still valid so I hope its not a problem.