# Getting a France Schengen visa but not going there

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, france, deception

I have applied for a France shengen visa but am not able to go in France. Instead am going to Italy and Austria and then London. so will there be any problem at immigration due to France Schengen visa or while departing outside of the Schengen area?

Comment: You don't mention one, but do make sure you also get a British visa; Schengen visas are no good in the UK.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/use-of-unused-schengen-visa-to-travel-to-switzerland?lq=1 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point

Comment: Is it possible that they wont know that i am not going to visit france. i have my air tickets for france. its just am not going to france but i do have the air tickets and hotel resrvations. from austria am straightaway going to london. and yes i do have a UK visa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may still be able to enter Italy/Austria instead of France. You may need to explain why - tell the truth, lying does not pay off.

If you have reasonable explanation, I'd expect you will be granted entry (maybe with a notice). It's likely to affect your ability to get French visas in future, but should not have huge effect on getting Schengen visas via other countries.

However if you have time, it's best to contact embassy of the main destination country of your trip (Italy or Austria) and ask them what's the best way to proceed. It may be better to apply for another visa, or to get an official letter from the embassy if they say another visa is not required.

As for London, it's in UK and UK is not in Schengen Area, so you will need separate visa for that.

Comment: Actually i am getting the visa from france because i want it urgently and i cant get a appointment for italy and austria visas. am travelling on 4th may so i really need to get the visa before 4th may.  so do you think i can get a visa before 4th may?

Comment: @IshanRanade this is totally different case and you should have mentioned this in your question. You should either reschedule your trip or ask Italian/Austrian embassy to process your application faster. Call them and explain your situations, they may be able to help.

Comment: @IshanRanade So you lied on your visa application about ever intending to visit France? This can and does cause problems to travellers.