# From Norway to other Schengen countries with a single visiting visa

Tags: schengen

Can I be allowed to move around within the Schengen zone on a single entry visiting visa of Norway, travelling from Norway to Germany or other Schengen countries before returning back to Norway for my final departure?

Answer (score 1):

In the application for a single-entry visa, you describe your purpose of travel and planned itinerary.

- If the visa is granted, you can use it for the planned purpose and itinerary and you are allowed to make **minor** adjustments to your route.
- With a single-entry visa, you can only enter Schengen once. Within Schengen you can cross as many internal borders as necessary.
- You are not allowed to misrepresent your intentions to get your visa. If you do use it for a **completely** different purpose, you may be suspected of fraud and it will be very difficult for you to convince the immigration officers that you did not lie.
- You are supposed to get your visa from the main destination of the trip. This is not always the first Schengen country on your itinerary.

Comment: “You are not allowed […]”: Actually, you are. The officers may indeed suspect you lied to get the visa and that's a good reason to be very careful but whether you lied or not is the only material fact. Changing one's mind and therefore using a visa for a completely different purpose is not forbidden *per se*. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/use-of-unused-schengen-visa-to-travel-to-switzerland for an example.

Comment: @Relaxed, edited. My intention was to steer the readers clear of trouble, not to encourage them to push the boundaries.