# What would happen if an invitation letter for Poland is ‘cancelled’?

Tags: visas, poland, invitation-letters

If someone want to send me an invitation letter from Poland, what is the government institution responsible for that? And he can cancel it during visa process and put me in bad situation? And if I got the visa then he cancels it, will it affect me at the airport? And how can the embassy make sure for that invitation letter?

Comment: I am not sure whether there is any specific procedure to cancel or verify something like that in Poland but note that if you won't be visiting the host (which would presumably be the case if the host wants to pull their invitation), pretending that you plan to do it would constitute fraud. If your trip has another purpose, you are supposed to disclose that to the consulate and/or border guards.

Comment: @Relaxed i will visit the host but may something happen , can make the host cancel the invitation during the visa process , it will affect me ?? , how the embassy verify the invitation ?

Comment: I understand the question and I don't know the details regarding Poland so I will let someone else answer. But it still makes little sense to me. If “something” happens and the host does not want to see you, will you still travel? For what purpose? You can't truthfully pretend it's to visit them! That's what I wanted to warn you about.

Comment: @Relaxed if i got the visa by the invitation , can i change my direction after arriving to the airport ?? , like i will say that i will stay at a hotel ?? , or the visa will be recorded with the host family only ?

Comment: You can make some changes, within reason, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point and many other similar questions on this site. But it sounds as if you are actually planning to do this from the get go, and that's definitely not allowed, irrespective of whether for border guards or the consulate can check it.

Comment: @Relaxed ok thank you .. waiting someone to answer about other inquiry for verify and cancel invitation letter process

Comment: @HeshamAbusaif, you are overthinking it

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, decisions are based on the document itself. It's only one element in the application like the rest of the supporting documentation you have to submit. Depending on the country and the type of invitation, it might bear some stamp or official signature that authenticates it (typically from a municipality) but it's probably not matched with a database and I am not sure whether consulates routinely contact anybody to verify them (although they obviously might).

Now, your comments to this and another question suggest that the invitation in question does not really exist anymore (i.e. you might have a letter stating this or that in your hand but you are not actually *invited* to participate in anything). If you apply for a visa based on this letter, you would submit materially incorrect information to the consulate and actively misrepresent your situation and intent. That's fraud, plain and simple, and could have very serious consequences. I don't know whether the consulate can easily detect it (they might notice something, e.g. during an interview) but that's still risky.

Ultimately, the invitation is just a document that attest something. What matters here is the underlying reality: The fact that you intend to participate in the project and that your host confirms that. If that's not true anymore, you should not hope the invitation to produce any effect. Because of this, a simple phone call would be enough to create serious difficulties for you. There is no need to formally cancel anything.

And *fraus omnia corrumpit*, any visa obtained that way can be annulled at any time, with all associated consequences up to detention, removal and a massive reduction of your credibility for any further visa application. You ask about the consulate and the border but an anonymous tip after you have entered the country would be enough too. If you do not intend to participate in this project, you should not pretend that you do.