# Change of plans in Schengen visa

Tags: passport-stamps

I have a Schengen visa issued from German consulate and my first entry and main entry country will be Germany. In my application form, I mentioned that I will visit Italy, too. However, I have changed my plans and I intend to go to Hungary instead of Italy. Is the exit country will be a problem for me? I mean is it possible that exit stamp from Hungary will be a problem in my future Schengen applications?

Comment: Whilst not an exact duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13362/1820 the principle of the visa having to be from the main country you stay in from the following answer will no doubt apply here.  So I think you'd be fine

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely to be a problem. Importantly, your visa *is perfectly valid for Hungary too*. Showing up somewhere completely different and not going to the country that issued the visa might be a problem (see [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782) and [Can I use my Schengen visa for a completely different purpose and entry point?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point)) but if you went to Germany on a German visa and did not overstay, I doubt any consulate would care about the point of exit.