# Can I enter Paris with Spain visa?

Tags: paris, barcelona, bcn, lebanese-citizens

I have a single entry visa to Spain but I decided recently to change my trip from Barcelona to Paris, the question is can I go to Paris with the issued visa?

Note that: there's no direct flight from Beirut to Barcelona.

Comment: @Karlson I actually think we have a better question about changing plans entirely somewhere - which has a rather different answer.

Comment: @CMaster http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point maybe? I think there are a couple other relevant questions. I also wrote a detailed answer to the “first trip” question covering various scenarios that might account for the differing answers but it's buried deep into the page.