# Can I travel from Rome to Amsterdam with a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a South African citizen and have a multiple entry visa obtained from the Italian Embassy. I am currently in Rome, can I travel from here to Amsterdam with my Schengen visa or do I need extra papers/documents/applications?

Comment: @Willeke The OP is already in the Schengen area...

Comment: When you are within Schengen you can travel without border controls, most of the time, and even when you are checked you should not have problems. I voted to close as the other answer has all information you need to explain this all.

Comment: @Relaxed, it does not make much of a difference whether you read the information before coming into the Schengen zone or when you are already there. I was going to add a comment explaining why I voted to close.

Comment: @Willeke My point is that it's not the same question at all…

Comment: Thanks to both... No its not the same question but the answer provides the required/ or enough information. Thanks again much appreciated! Its my forst time on this site and its very quick and useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

No, you don't need any additional documentation. Your visa, which does allow you to go to the Netherlands or [even to enter it directly from South Africa on a subsequent trip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point) will probably not be checked by anybody. You will almost certainly need your passport to board the plane however.