# Can I use my Schengen business visa for a holiday?

Tags: schengen

I have six-month multiple-entry business Schengen visa, issued by the French Embassy.

I am planing to go to France for business (or work) in June and then come back home, a non-European country.

In July, I want to go to Spain and Italy for holidays.

- Can I use this visa for a holiday only (no business during the trip)?
- Do I need to enter Europe first through France?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the United States, there's no split between "business" and "holiday" visas. For example, check this [document](http://eeas.europa.eu/archives/delegations/south_africa/documents/schengen_visa_requirments_en.pdf) listing -- among many other things -- the categories of visas:

- Short stay visa: a “Schengen” visa one or multiple entries, allowing the holder to stay in the Schengen
  Territory up to 90 days per 6 months
- Long stay visa: Visas for stays exceeding 90 days are national visas, and are issued by member states in
  accordance with national legislation.
- Airport transit visas: required by the nationals of certain countries. (Not for R.S.A. citizens).

As for going to Spain on a visa issued by France, there won't be any problems especially if you visited France already. I will try to find an official source for this, until then check this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26940/4188).